# Why i can not save list in c# list?

Tags: c#

I'm new in `c#` and write this class:

```
public class MANAGER
    {
        public string VersionName { get; set; }
        public Double Value { get; set; }

    }
```

and use this:

```
List<MANAGER> lstSummary = new List<MANAGER>();
MANAGER summary = new MANAGER();
summary.VersionName = "12";
summary.Value =12;
lstSummary.Add(summary);
summary.VersionName = "13";
summary.Value = 19;
lstSummary.Add(summary);
```

but up code just save latest class record ,means just save `VersionName=13 and Value=19`,How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to re-instantiate the `summary` variable like so:

```
MANAGER summary = new MANAGER();
summary.VersionName = "12";
summary.Value =12;
lstSummary.Add(summary);

summary = new MANAGER(); // <-- add this
summary.VersionName = "13";
summary.Value = 19;
lstSummary.Add(summary);
```

Comment: after 5 minute accept your answer,thanks for help me

Answer (score 2):

The problem as described in another answer is that you add the same object to the list multiple times, so you need to have a separate one. You can do it that way or don't use explicit the variable at all, since C# allows initializers. It will be pretty much the same logic, but a bit more nice and readable.

```
var lstSummary = new List<MANAGER>
{
    new Manager
    {
        VersionName = "12",
        Value = 12
    },
    new Manager
    {
        VersionName = "13",
        Value = 19
    }
}
```